# "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)" error from str.split()

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I get rid of the error as I don't find anything wrong in it while using the `split()` function.

```
import json
file=open('csv.txt','r')
lines=[line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]
jsonlist=[]
for item in lines:
  club,country,city=item.split(',')
  data={
         'club':club,
         'country':country,
         'city':city
     }
  jsonlist.append(data)

jsonfile=open('jsontxt','w')
json.dump(jsonlist,jsonfile)
file.close()
jsonfile.close()
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: Hi there! You'll need to show us a sample of what `csv.txt` looks like. Without a [mcve], all we can do is guess.

Comment: Before split check the item value